# How to inform a web interface about the status of a variable?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Spring MVC for a web app(with JQuery for front-end). I have a service that has a status variable that changes based on the progress of a certain method.

The code looks like the following:

```
@Service
public class PatchGenerationService {
 private String status;

 public String getStatus() {
     return status;
 }

 public void generatePatch(){
      status = STATUS_PREPARE;
      //some code 
      status = STATUS_LOOKUP;
      //and so on
      status = STATUS_FINISHED;
 }
}
```

There are several asynchronous threads running this service at the same time, created by different clients. I want to be able to inform each client on the status of the thread created for him.

Here is the service where the `PatchGenerationService` is created:

```
@Async
public static void createPatchFromSelectedCommits(String branch, String tagName, List<Commit> commits) {
    log.info("generating a new patch");
    PatchGenerationService patchGenerationService = new PatchGenerationService();
    patchGenerationService.generatePatch(/*attributes*/);
    log.info("patch generation ended");
}
```

How can I send the information with the value of the status variable to the client each time this variable changes?

Comment: Should be `setInterval(getGenerationProgress, 100)`

Comment: thanks, corrected the typo

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look to this documentation : [**Using WebSocket to build an interactive web application**](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

> ### Using WebSocket to build an interactive web application
>
> This guide walks you through the process of creating a "hello world"
>   application that sends messages back and forth, between a browser and
>   the server. WebSocket is a very thin, lightweight layer above TCP. It
>   makes it very suitable to use "subprotocols" to embed messages. In
>   this guide we’ll dive in and use STOMP messaging with Spring to create
>   an interactive web application.

In simple words, your backend will send a message to your frontend to notify him of the change of status.

Comment: ok I have implemented this, but the problem is that my service is @Async and there are many instances of PatchGenerationService created, each having its own status, how can I pass the specific one to the controller?

Comment: I don't see your point. You don't keep track of the `PatchGenerationService` you created, it looks like a problem to me.

Comment: that is my problem, I don't know how to keep track of that object

Comment: Well, you can use List or Map with IDs on each object. Your call.

Comment: I will edit my question so that it would be more clear

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the answer in this project: [Github Link](https://github.com/frenos/spring-mvc-async-progress)

In fact it would have been rather difficult to retrieve the specific `PatchGenerationService` object. I have thus modified the class so that it implements `Runnable`.

I now override the run method in `PatchGenerationService`:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    generatePatch( patchName,  branchName,  tagName,  version,  author,  applierRelease,  selectedCommits);
}
```

I am using STOMP with SockJS in order to send messages to the client every time the statuts variable changes:

```
public void sendProgress(String exception){
    logger.info("status:" +status);
    Status statusWithException=new Status(status,exception);
    template.convertAndSend("/generationStatus/status", statusWithException);
}

public void generatePatch(String patchName, String branchName, String tagName, String version, String author, String applierRelease, List<Commit> selectedCommits) {

    //String status;
    status = STATUS_PREPARE;
    sendProgress("");
}
```

The connection is managed by a broker:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/generationStatus");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/status").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

The connect method on the client side subscribes to the `generationStatus/status` url:

```
function connect() {
    console.log('connecting to generation status');
    var socket = new SockJS('/status');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/generationStatus/status', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
}
```